# Getting wget to dowload only files with specific name patterns

Tags: wget

I want to use wget to DL some files. I want to DL only files whose name that fit a certain pattern, e.g. ???.txt and not any other *.txt files.
Can this be done with wget?
I could only find a way to --accept/--reject files based on the extension.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `-A` option with `--accept`
Example : to download all the gif images from the website,

```
wget -r -A gif www.foobar.com
```

or

```
wget -r --accept=gif www.foobar.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are downloading from an website, you don't -- HTTP doesn't support wildcards.  But you can use the --mirror option which will try to mirror the entire site.  Try mixing the --mirror and the --accept and see what happens.